# showing a hint message upon hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I followed a tutorial on how to make a photo gallery using jQuery plugins and HTML and I'm trying to make some amendments to it. Normally when I click on an image it zooms out but I want to add a hint such that when I click on the image it shows a certain hint message. For example if I click on an image it shows a hint: this is message number 1.

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Pure CSS3 photo gallery | Script Tutorials</title>
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" id="container">
            <div class="gallery">
                <a tabindex="1"><img src="images/1.jpg"> </a>
                <a tabindex="1"><img src="images/2.jpg"></a>
        <span class="close"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

But I want to add something like this:

```
<a tabindex="1"><img src="images/1.jpg"> <p class="hint">image 43 </p></a>
```

And in the CSS I add something like this

```
.gallery:hover .hint{
    margin:-30px 0 0 450px;
}
```

I'm not very good, but I would love to learn this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show what's in the script.js, because that script is the zoom in function. If you can edit that than u can choose what u want to show

Answer (score 1):

jquery tooltip will be useful for you. Actually what tooltip is to show some text on some element to provide information regarding the element.

```
       <input id="j" title="please enter the details." />
```

If you write like this it shows the information which is present in the title attribute. Jquery helps in giving a better look.
Here is the fiddle have a look at it 
**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9RmJN/1/)**

I hope you understood the concept.

Comment: Can you please comment you post a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.hint').each(function(){
    $(this).hover(function(){
        // in this function show your hint/tooltip
    },
    function(){
        // and hide it here
    });
});
```

Demo:

```js
$('.hint').each(function() {
  $(this).hover(function() {
      // in this function show your hint/tooltip
      $('<div></div>')
        .addClass('tooltip')
        .text('this is ' + $(this).text())
        .appendTo('body')
        .css({
          top: $(this).offset().top,
          left: $(this).offset().left + 50
        });

    },
    function() {
      // and hide it here
      $('.tooltip').remove();
    });
});
```

```css
div.hint {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}
div.tooltip {
  position: absolute
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='hint'>foo</div>
<br/>
<div class='hint'>bar</div>
<br/>
<div class='hint'>cat</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is only an example but is this what you are trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/7RZHJ/
If you can show the codes in `script.js` than we can see what u need to edit